# Error installing kivyMD (kivy material design)

Tags: python, material-design, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to install kivyMD, which is a kivy material theme, on my ubuntu computer.
https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD

I have installed kivy, and the example from kivy website run fine.

I have installed kivyMD with these command from their gitlab:

```
pip install kivy-garden
garden install recycleview
```

When I try to run the example `kitchen_sink.py`, I get an error.
Here is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/max/Documents/KivyMD/kitchen_sink.py", line 2, in <module>
     import kivymd.snackbar as Snackbar
   File "/home/max/Documents/KivyMD/kivymd/snackbar.py", line 50, in <module>
     ''')
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1491, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1049, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1119, in parse
     self.execute_directives()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1083, in execute_directives
     mod = __import__(package)
   File "/home/max/Documents/KivyMD/kivymd/button.py", line 28, in <module>
     from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
   File "/home/max/Documents/KivyMD/kivymd/theming.py", line 20, in <module>
     class ThemeManager(Widget):
   File "/home/max/Documents/KivyMD/kivymd/theming.py", line 52, in ThemeManager
     bind=('primary_palette', 'primary_hue'))
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 1176, in kivy.properties.AliasProperty.__init__ (kivy/properties.c:19156)
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
pip3 install kivymd
```

It works fine for me, and you need to install kivyMD in the Python3 directory, kivy only works with `python=>3.5`

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/27124610) your answer when you'd like to extend or change it – don't use comments for that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

I forgot to add the ppa before installing kivy.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```